# Working with rename function in PHP

Tags: php

There is a file within the directory and I am trying to use rename( arg1, arg2 ) to rename the arg1 file.

However, the arg1 file contains Asian letters and I get the message that the file is not available.

how can I solve this issue

thanks

```
    $elements = scandir($dir);


foreach ($elements as $key => $value) 
{

    rename("./$value", "$newname");

}
```

Comment: I think you need: `rename("./" . $value, $newname);`

Comment: You try to rename with the relative path `./` , is your PHP file in the current dir where you try to make rename ?<br />
Because if your PHP script is not in the same folder, you have to path the whole way to `rename`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to put the paths correctly:

```
$elements = scandir($dir);
foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
    rename($dir.'/'.$value, $dir.'/'.$newname);
}
```

To be less abstract, assume $dir is something like "/home/someuser/somefiles" and your script is located at "/var/www/script.php", you are getting all files (e.g. "oldname.txt") from scandir($dir), so the absolute path to the file is "/home/someuser/somefiles/oldname.txt", but you are passing "./oldname.txt" to the rename function, which is in fact "/var/www/oldname.txt"